# What does a Keras TimeDistributed layer actually do?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

Given a time-series, I have a multi-step forecasting task, where I want to forecast the same number of times as time steps in a given sequence of the time-series.
If I have the following model:

```
input1 = Input(shape=(n_timesteps, n_channels))
lstm = LSTM(units=100, activation='relu')(input1)
outputs = Dense(n_timesteps, activation="softmax")(lstm)
model = Model(inputs=input1, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam",
              metrics=["accuracy"])
```

The n_timesteps on the dense layer means that I will have n_timesteps predictions. But if I wrap the dense layer in a TimeDistributed (or equivalently set return_sequences=True in the LSTM layer), does the number of units still have to be n_timesteps or is it 1, since with the TimeDistributed I would be applying the dense layer to all the times steps in the sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the example you posted, the [TimeDistributed](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/TimeDistributed) will essentially apply a `Dense` layer with a `softmax` activation function to each timestep:

```
import tensorflow as tf

n_timesteps = 10
n_channels = 30
input1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(n_timesteps, n_channels))
lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=100, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)(input1)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_channels, activation="softmax"))(lstm)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input1, outputs=outputs)
```

Note that each fully connected layer is equal to the size of the `n_channels` in order to give each channel a fair chance of being predicted at timestep `n`.

If you are working on a multi-label problem, you can try something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

n_timesteps = 10
features = 3
input1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(n_timesteps, features))
lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=100, activation='relu', return_sequences=False)(input1)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_timesteps, activation="sigmoid")(lstm)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input1, outputs=outputs)

x = tf.random.normal((1, n_timesteps, features))
y = tf.random.uniform((1, n_timesteps), dtype=tf.int32, maxval=2)

print(x)
print(y)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
model.fit(x, y, epochs=2)
```

Comment: Almost, I wanted to get a prediction per timestep, hence the number of units of the Dense Layer being n_timesteps. Would this work or would it be doing a forecast and not a classification task?

Comment: Yes, you said it right.. it would be a forecasting task and not a classification task. Meaning a `softmax` function makes little sense then.

Comment: So there isn't a way to do multi-step classification with an LSTM then? Even if I give a series and limit the output of the Dense Layer to be a number between 0 and 1 (binary classification task)

Comment: So you want to actually predict `x` timesteps given `n` previous timesteps? @DPM

Comment: I want to predict a binary variable for every timestep. And each timestep has 3 features/channels